# Error when click on continue in the checkout screen

Tags: magento2

this error happens when the user tries to advance from the checkout screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of your layout files, don't know which one, contains inside the tag `<head>` a tag called `<js>` which is not allowed.